# multiple constraints in z3py if conditional

Tags: z3, z3py

Let us assume we have 2 functions (`funcA` and `funcB`) that builds some constraints in Z3's current context.

I want to guard those in a Z3 if block. In z3py, you would write:

```py
t = If(some_condition, funcA(), funcB())
```

This is dependent on the fact that `funcA` and `funcB` return some z3 expression. What if I want to represent them as a function call that builds a bunch of constraints rather than returning an expression, what would be a simpler way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd turn them into (pseduo-code):

```
for c in funcA():
   s.add(Implies(some_condition, c))

for c in funcB():
   s.add(Implies(Not(some_condition), c))
```

Comment: Ah I see, what you are doing here. I can change funcA and funcB to do this implication. But is there any better way to get the list of constraints from a function (just like you do in this pseduo-code)

Comment: If you implement your constraints just as booleans then you can easily do this. If your functions `funcA`/`funcB` actually do the `s.add` calls, then I'm afraid you're out of luck. You should change them back to return the booleans. (Or you can make them take `some_condition` as a parameter and do the right thing internally.)